# How to configure model to not create tables in flask sqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How to configure sqlAlchemy to not create tables in flask sqlAlchemy?

i only use flask-sqlalchemy Model's features,but won't create table.

How to configure this？

because i want to use in sql View,if run db.create_all(),View become to table.

thanks.

this is a View!

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from settings.dataBase import CRUDMixin, db


class ViewExample(db.Model, CRUDMixin):
    __tablename__ = "view_example"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    is_albums = db.Column(db.Integer)
    is_attach = db.Column(db.Integer)
    is_spec = db.Column(db.Integer)
    sort_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'id : %s' % self.id
```

i find a example,but i dont know how to use in flask-sqlalchemy.
alembic slqlalchemy document:
https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#don-t-emit-create-table-statements-for-views

flask-migrate env.py 
i add a include_object func ,but dont get is_view.

```py
from __future__ import with_statement

import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
logger = logging.getLogger('alembic.env')

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
from flask import current_app

config.set_main_option(
    'sqlalchemy.url', current_app.config.get(
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI').replace('%', '%%'))
target_metadata = current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.metadata


# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.
def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    """
    Exclude views from Alembic's consideration.
    """
    print(object.info)
    return not object.info.get('is_view', False)


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url, target_metadata=target_metadata, literal_binds=True,
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    # this callback is used to prevent an auto-migration from being generated
    # when there are no changes to the schema
    # reference: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html
    def process_revision_directives(context, revision, directives):
        if getattr(config.cmd_opts, 'autogenerate', False):
            script = directives[0]
            if script.upgrade_ops.is_empty():
                directives[:] = []
                logger.info('No changes in schema detected.')

    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            include_object=include_object,# add 
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

add `__table_args__ = { "info": dict(is_view=True)}` is good.

```py
class ViewExample(db.Model, CRUDMixin):
    __tablename__ = "view_example"
    __table_args__ = { "info": dict(is_view=True)} # add
```

thanks！ this questions been solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `__abstract__ = True` in the model that your don't want to create

Comment: but can not use flask-sqlalchemy Model's features then can not  query. 
example: `table.query.filter_by(id=1).first() `
so i only use `__table_args__ = { "info": dict(is_view=True)}`.

Comment: `__abstract__ = True` use in mixin

Answer (score 2):

if you are not using alembic, the answer given here is not full.
what you need to do is change the metadata class that comes with base.Model in the following way:

```
class ViewAwareMetaData(MetaData):
def __init__(self):
    super(ViewAwareMetaData, self).__init__()
    
def create_all(self, bind=None, tables=None, checkfirst=True):
    tables = [table for table in tables if not table.info.get('is_view', False)]
    super().create_all(bind=bind, tables=tables, checkfirst=checkfirst)
```

and then use the new meta when initializaing sqlalchemy:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(engine_options=engine_options, metadata=ViewAwareMetaData())
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, I have tables which are created & populated during a Docker build process and needed some way to prevent these from being deleted by my unit test teardown functions. Works like a charm!